I can't find the compiler error in my script
enter image description here
The code is for a stamina bar, pressing/ holding F should decrease it by 2 for each frame it's pressed down
I don't see the problem here, When I try to run the scene it says all compiler errors must be fixed and I know its coming from here.
I've double checked and maybe I'm just dumb but I can't see the problem here

You should never have to spot compilation errors by eyeballing the code. Your development environment and/or compiler should list the specific compilation errors when you build the project.

Take a look at your "StaminaBar" variable, it doesnt exist..

Please include as text within the question rather than as a screenshot.

You misspelled the image variable at the top naming it "stamina" also.
You cant have you properties with the same name.
Your code may look like this:
public class Stamina : MonoBehaviour
{
   Image staminaBar;   //THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR WAS
   float maxStamina = 100f;
   public float stamina;

   void Start(){
      staminaBar = GetComponent<Image>();
      stamina = maxStamina;
   }

   //Update code and so on
}

